# User Defined Function Seems to be Doubling Past Inputs

Tags: python

With the code I currently have set up values seems to double and I can't pinpoint why.

For example ill run an array (E) though a function and get `[5.569, 10.9536, 16.167, ...]`then when I run that function again later with array (G) and suddenly (E) will now read `[11.137, 21.90721, 32.3342, ...]`

Those numbers seem to be exactly double of what the array initially was and should be. Below is the function being used? What is going wrong??

Script 1:

```py
    E = PyFunctions.za(c_v, 4)
    F = PyFunctions.za(c_v, 6)
    G = PyFunctions.zb(E, F, 2)
```

Script 2:

```py
    def zb(e1, e2, p):
    l1 = len(e1)
    l2 = len(e2)

    if l1 > l2:
        e1 = e1[(-1 - l2) + 1:]
    elif l2 > l1:
        e2 = e2[(-1 - l1) + 1:]

    e1p = e1
    e1p[:] = [x * p for x in e1p]
    e2p = e2
    e2p[:] = [x * (p - 1) for x in e2p]

    z = [0] * len(e1p)

    for k in range(len(e1p)):
        z[k] = e1p[k] - e2p[k]
    return z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an effect of [Python aliasing](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/thinkcspy/Lists/Aliasing.html). Because you're passing in `E` to `zb()` as `e1`, `e1` is exactly `E`, and on the line where you say:

```
e1p = e1
```

you are establishing an aliasing relationship between `e1` and `e1p`, and therefore between `E` and `e1p`. Then, when on the next line you multiply each of the elements in `e1p` by `p`:

```
e1p[:] = [x * p for x in e1p]
```

you are actually doing that action on `E` (because of aliasing), so therefore each of the elements in `E` is being multiplied by `p` (which you passed in as 2), so that is why `E` is being doubled.

If you wanted to only pass in a *copy* of `E` into `zb()`, you could have replaced the third line in Script 1 with this:

```
G = PyFunctions.zb(E[:], F, 2)
```